# GridDB Go Client Connection Pooling Issue: Identifying and Resolving Leaked Connections

Tags: griddb

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/griddb/go-client/gs"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // GridDB connection settings
    factory := gs.GetFactory()
    gridstore, err := factory.GetGridStore(gs.NewGridStoreInfo("your_cluster", "your_database", "your_username", "your_password"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error connecting to GridDB: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer gridstore.Close()

    // Simulate a high-throughput application with frequent GridDB connections
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        // Perform some database operations (e.g., insert, query)
        // ...

        // Close the connection explicitly to avoid leaks
        err := gridstore.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error closing GridDB connection: %v\n", err)
        }

        // Wait for a while before reusing the connection
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    }

    fmt.Println("GridDB Go Client Connection Pooling Issue: Identifying and Resolving Leaked Connections")
}
```

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with the GridDB Go client in my high-throughput application. The application establishes and closes GridDB connections frequently, but I suspect that some connections are leaking or not being properly released, leading to resource exhaustion and performance degradation.

Connection Pooling Issue: Despite explicitly calling gridstore.Close() to close connections after each database operation, I suspect that some connections are not being released and are accumulating over time. This has resulted in performance issues and resource consumption concerns. How can I identify and resolve this connection pooling issue in the GridDB Go client?

Connection Cleanup Strategies: The provided code snippet simulates the frequent opening and closing of GridDB connections. Are there additional strategies or best practices for managing connections in a high-throughput environment to prevent leaks and optimize resource utilization?

Monitoring and Diagnostics: What tools or techniques can I use to monitor and diagnose connection-related issues in the GridDB Go client? Are there specific metrics or logs that I should examine to identify connection leaks or bottlenecks?

Code Sample: I've included code that demonstrates the issue I'm facing. Please review the code and provide insights, recommendations, or code modifications that can help identify and resolve the connection pooling issue and ensure proper connection management in the GridDB Go client.

I'm seeking expert guidance on troubleshooting connection pooling issues and optimizing connection management in the GridDB Go client for a high-throughput application. Your expertise in diagnosing and resolving such issues would be greatly appreciated.